# Spring MVC - HTTP Status 404 - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

Attempting to create a Spring MVC hello world web app.  It is currently returning HTTP Status 404.  404 means it can't find the file, but I'm not sure why.  I think my servlet.xml is pointing to the appropriate folder (component-scan).  I think all the files are named correctly(no typos).  See the picture for the error.

[image: Error]

servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="helloworld" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package helloworld;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "hello-world";
    }
}
```

hello-world.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>
```

[image: Project Explorer]

Comment: Yes, The servlet.xml and the web.xml were not under WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet.xml and the web.xml were not under WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

The RequestMapping is pointed to "/" in the controller. try making a call to http://localhost:8080/